# How can I use the background color value of a cell as a condition in an if-statement driven formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, background-color

I am facing a big challenge in extracting a cell's background color and using it as a conditional in Google Sheets. The idea is to write a custom formula in Apss Script and execute it in an if-statement so that when the background color of a cell turns blue it returns 1; otherwise, it returns 0.

Also, at some point, the code was working when editing the cell value, but later it did not update. Is there any way to use this code with a constant update of the background color?

In case it is easier to imagine, the background color will serve as a toggle, indicating to the user when a payment was made and eliminating the amount in a table.

Thank you very much in advance.

Cheers,

JB

So far, I have written/ modified this code

```
function ColoredCells(countRange) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();

  return color;
};
```

While the formula is:

```
if(ColoredCells(E2)="#00ff00",1,0)
```

This result should be 1, and when changing the background color to "red", it should return 0.

I want to write the formula with the selected cell as an argument, but I do not know how. Can you please also give me a hand with an explanation or book that I can look into for more information? I highly appreciate it. =)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `Also, at some point, the code was working when editing the cell value, but later it did not update. Is there any way to use this code with a constant update of the background color?` and your showing script? Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi Tanaike,

I appreciate your help. Let me rephrase my question: how can I extract the cell's background color and use its value as part of a condition in an if-statement?

The script you are asking for is the one posted. I have tried this other one:

function bgHex(cellAddress) {
 var mycell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellAddress);
 var bghex = mycell.getBackground();
 return bghex;
};

Here is the formula in Sheets: 

In C1 copy this formula: =if(bgHex(CELL("address", A1))=$B$1,1,0)

B1 = #00ff00

C1 should prompt value 1

Once again, thank you. 

JB

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, I cannot understand the relationship between `Also, at some point, the code was working when editing the cell value, but later it did not update. Is there any way to use this code with a constant update of the background color?` and your showing script. And also, it seems that the script of your reply is different from your question. Now, I'm confused about your question. Can I ask you the detail of your question? I deeply apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, no worries. My idea is having a formula that updates automatically the resulting value after the background color changes. However, this is not happening in either of the scripts I shared. Also, you are right, the second script was a form another post, but still has the same issue with updating the resulting value. I need a code that updates its output value when I change the background color of a cell. If there any way to keep the updating value feature of Google Sheets with custom formulas? For example, the same feature when adding = A1 + B1 in cell C1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I would like to confirm whether my understanding of your expected result is correct. You want to update the cell value of the custom function when the background of the cell is changed. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you, for helping me. Exactly, I want to use an if-statement to prompt 1, when the background color of the cell is green, and 0 when is red. But I want to be able to change the color between green and red, several times, which means the resulting value will also update dynamically. Is that possible? Or should I find a workaround? You can find some similarity with a checkbox, resulting in TRUE or FALSE, but using colors instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I couldn't understand whether my understanding is correct. But, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi Tanaike. No worries. Your understanding of the question was correct. i appreciate your help.